# ExpressionEngine Stash Replacing rather than appending

Tags: stash, php

I'd massively appreciate a bit of help with the Stash ExpressionEngine plugin...
I think it must be quite simple but feel like I've tried everything...

The {expertise} tag is an ExpressionEngine grid field and contains multiple grid rows. I want to store these in stash - it's working to store them once but is always replaced when I run it again... I want what's stored in stash to constantly append rather than blanking the variable and starting again each time is is run...

Any ideas?

Many thanks in advance for any help!

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="barristers" url_title="{segment_3}" status="open" sort="asc" disable="pagination"}

<p>Adding {title}'s full CV (all the skills)...</p>

{expertise}

{exp:stash:append scope="user" save="yes" name="skills" output="yes" replace="no"}
{expertise:row_id},
{/exp:stash:append}

{/expertise}

<p>IN SESSION: {exp:stash:get name="skills"}</p>

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would wrap the grid field with stash set_list instead of append. You can add output="yes" to view what's being set in the database with the set_list (or better yet, check out [Mustash](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mustash)).

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="barristers" url_title="{segment_3}" status="open" sort="asc" disable="pagination" limit="1"}

    Adding {title}'s full CV (all the skills)...

    {exp:stash:set_list
        name="skills" 
        scope="user" 
        save="yes" 
        replace="no" 
        parse_tags="yes"
    }
        {expertise}
            {stash:expertise_row_id}{expertise:row_id}{/stash:expertise_row_id}
        {/expertise}
    {/exp:stash:set_list}


    IN SESSION: 
        {exp:stash:get_list 
            name="skills"
            scope="user"
            backspace="2"
        }
            {expertise_row_id}, 
        {/exp:stash:get_list}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```